# How to create power profile with power.cfg in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, power-management

My power managment profiles has vaporized I cannot edit them, delete or make new ones cause every new one is copy of the existing which is corrupted. I found out that there is tool called power.cfg but all tutorials show everything beside useful stuff: how to create a power scheme using power.cfg?

Comment: somthing is seriously wrong there. can you edit the powercfg ui's with another user? if not, you may want to run 'sft.exe /SCANNOW' to see if portions of your OS are corrupt.

Comment: As Frank said, run `sfc /scannow` first from an elevated command prompt. If that doesn't help, you can try exporting everything under the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\User` key from another Win7 PC using regedit and importing into your PC's registry. Perhaps it will help repair the 3 default power schemes.